# Cordova have SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I installed cordova using:

> npm install cordova -g

I get the error when I run the following command:

> cordova -v

```
? May Cordova anonymously report usage statistics to improve the tool over time? (Y/n) Invalid regular expression: /.{1,0}/: numbers out of order in {} quantifier
n? May Cordova anonymously report usage statistics to improve the tool over time? (Y/n) n

readline.js:1021
            throw err;
            ^

SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /.{1,0}/: numbers out of order in {} quantifier
    at new RegExp (<anonymous>)
    at breakLines (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/insight/node_modules/inquirer/lib/utils/screen-manager.js:108:15)
    at module.exports.ScreenManager.render (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/insight/node_modules/inquirer/lib/utils/screen-manager.js:55:22)
    at Prompt.render (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/insight/node_modules/inquirer/lib/prompts/confirm.js:85:15)
    at Prompt.onKeypress (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/insight/node_modules/inquirer/lib/prompts/confirm.js:109:10)
    at AnonymousObserver.Rx.AnonymousObserver.AnonymousObserver.next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/insight/node_modules/rx-lite/rx.lite.js:1535:12)
    at AnonymousObserver.Rx.internals.AbstractObserver.AbstractObserver.onNext (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/insight/node_modules/rx-lite/rx.lite.js:1469:31)
    at AnonymousObserver.tryCatcher (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/insight/node_modules/rx-lite/rx.lite.js:63:31)
    at AutoDetachObserverPrototype.next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/insight/node_modules/rx-lite/rx.lite.js:5782:51)
    at AutoDetachObserver.Rx.internals.AbstractObserver.AbstractObserver.onNext (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/insight/node_modules/rx-lite/rx.lite.js:1469:31)
```

How can I fix it?

> cat /etc/os-release

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.1 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

> node -v

v8.10.0

> npm -v

3.5.2

Comment: Can you run this command 'cordova telemetry off'? and then try again. Hope it works

Comment: It works now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, and I'm glad you got your solution, but I had the same error today and I solved it with the error message itself. This part: "/.{1,0}/: numbers out of order in {} quantifier." I just put the numbers in order and it worked.

```
if (blob[i].match(/.{0,1}/g) || blob[i].match(/.{0,1}/g)) {
  arr.push(blob[i])
}
```